# How to force a service to run from a specified directory in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to create a service that will automatically start my Rails server. Since the `rails server` command works correctly only in the application directory, I use the `/lib/systemd/system/dev.fhc.name.service` file with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma development server for fhc.name domain

[Service]
ExecStart=cd /home/fhc/www && screen -dmS dev.fhc.name rails server -u puma -e development -p 3001
ExecStop=screen -X -S dev.fhc.name quit
Type=idle
KillMode=process

SyslogIdentifier=dev-fhc-name
SyslogFacility=daemon

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, trying to run it:

```
sudo systemctl start dev.fhc.name
```

Leads to an error:

> Aug 25 23:00:51 fhc.name systemd[1]:
> /lib/systemd/system/dev.fhc.name.service:5: Executable "cd" not found
> in path "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200654/executing-chdir-before-starting-systemd-service

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1063395/680869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063395/680869) you should use directive `WorkingDirectory`. Do not forget other directives like `ExecStart` should have full path.

And for me usage of `screen` look a bit odd and not in place.

Comment: For some reason, Puma won't start with the `-d` flag. It writes a success notification as a daemon, and immediately stops without any errors. So you have to use `screen`.

Comment: You don't start services daemonized with systemd.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes, you're right, I didn't think about removing it when transferring the command to the service. True, now the question arises, how to write the command to stop this particular server in ExecStop?

Comment: rails should create a pid file. Use it in systemd.